# Auth::user() Returns Null (Laravel + Passport)

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

- Laravel 7.5.2
- Passport 8.4.3
- Vuejs: 2.5.17

Hello everyone. I'm working on a Laravel project and I have a problem like so:

I have some api controllers and in one of them, I need to use Auth::user() to create some logic. I'm not interested in returning user details to Vuejs backend. I just one to use it in an api contoller.

- I can fetch data by using api,
- I can get Auth::user() data in blade template,
- Redirct to /home works, when I log in.

Based on these 3 points, I assume that Passport is working properly, or they have nothing to do with Passport, I don't know. But when I try to use Auth::user() in a controller, it always return the value as if Auth::user() is NULL.

I think I set up Passport properly, since I did it 3 times through documentation. I have tried every single solution that I was able to find, but none of them worked for me. They might be outdated. I really appreciate that if someone can help me on this issue.

web.php

```php
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'BackendController@index')->name('home');
```

BackendController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class BackendController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        // $user is not NULL here. In balde view, I can console log $user.
        return view('layouts.backend')->with("user", $user);
    }
}
```

/home is Vuejs home page.

api.php

```php
Route::apiResources([
    'please' => 'API\HelpMeController'
]);
```

API/HelpMeController

```php
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::user() || auth()->user() || auth()->guard('api')->user()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0; // it returns this one.
    }
}
```

P.S.: I haven't share too many codes since all authentication files remains the same as if it's installed fresh. The only difference is that I'm using a custom named users table with a few extra fields instead the default one.

Comment: Did you authenticate via Passport or the default login provided by Laravel?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I installed default autentication first, and then followed the documentation to install and setup Passport. I use default login forms and controllers but I don't know if I'm authenticated by Passport.